# Validate the excel sheet

Tags: php, excel, validation

I have used the PHP method `<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` for uploading the excel sheets. Now I want to validate the excel sheet.

**Validation:**

If the sheet contain image instead of text I need to give an error to the user. Is it possible to validate the sheet's content without opening the sheet manually?

Comment: can you extend - "Now I want to validate the excel sheet."

Comment: No it isn't... PHP (like most languages) has no concept of Excel, or PDF or any specific file format, until you open that file and verify it - a file is just a file to PHP until it's opened and validated. If you want to work with Excel files, you need a library that can "understand" the structure and content of Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = $_POST['your_field_file'];
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
```

or this

```
$filename = "/home/user1/whatever.xls"; //or $_POST['your_field_file'];
echo $finfo->file($filename);
```

It will return the MIME type, verify if it is excell file, then you can look the file size, and put some restrictions, but if you want to know what have inside the file, I think you need to open or parse the file. Try to use `file_get_contents()` and verify line by line if has an image there. (I'm not sure about that)

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to use the data from the Excel file, you would have to parse and read it. If you can parse it as an Excel file, then its probably Excel, then you can safely rely on a php library like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

On the other hand, if you don't plan on using the data from the excel file, I personnally think that it would be overkill to use an entire library to validate if a file is in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should make use of the [`fileinfo` PHP extension](http://php.net/fileinfo) to check the mime types of the files users are uploading.